# Image drag-drop from one canvas to another

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I've a problem from past few days. I'm new to HTML5, and I'm trying to do a drag-drop of multiple images from one canvas to another canvas and vice-versa.

I have looked upon multiple links but none have helped so far, mostly because those links have only one canvas for drag-drop in only that canvas.

Like this link: http://simonsarris.com/blog/225-canvas-selecting-resizing-shape

But I want something like this in HTML5: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Comment: CROSS-POST: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/471870/dragplusandplusdropplusmultipleplusimageplusfrompl

Answer (score -2):

You cannot drag-drop from one canvas to another. The `SVG` objects are **bound to** their parent canvas container.

But if what you want to do something that CSS can do for your graphical needs, then I can recommend you this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: Do you even know what an `SVG` is? I doubt that you do. I didn't link the page to show something that has to do with `SVG`, I gave an alternative to a solution that doesn't exists. Get a hold on your language skills and stop downvoting based on your erroneous judgments. @Richard

Comment: Yes yes yes - you can drag 'n' drop images between canvas tags - and there's a demo here: http://dev.rgraph.net/tests/_misc/drag-n-drop.html

Comment: Then should've told it in the first place, rather than voting down and saying like an incapable person who's unable to grasp the information in the correct manner, "There's no SVG on that page". @Richard